# How to pass a variable from URI as argument for ASP.NET WebAPI action method?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2

I had this working before and now I do not. But, I cannot see what I have done to make it not work?

This is my MVC API Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public Models.CustomerAddress Add(string Customer)
{
    //the customer is a json string
}
```

This is my C# desktop Client:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Shared.URL);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(Shared.HeaderType));
    string jsonInput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer);
    HttpContent contentPost = new StringContent(jsonInput, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
   var response = client.PostAsync(string.Format("http://myuri/api/Customer/Add?Customer="), contentPost).Result;
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.CustomerAddress>(json);
}
```

The customer object is definitely populated...

This does call my api but the Customer string is null??

Comment: Is the `customer` object just a string, or something more complex?  Also, why are you passing an empty `Customer` query string parameter?  That may be confusing the model binder.

Comment: Hi, the Customer Object has fields like surname and firstname etc.  If I point a breakpoint on it the object is populated.  I am not sure what you mean by empty Customer string.  I thought this was the way to pass in a JSON object?

Comment: @closer why?  This question is a programming question. What is not programmatic about it? Confused?

Comment: Are you sure that controller is the right one? The URL would lead me to think it should be `Customer` rather than `CustomerAddress`

Comment: @JBKing Yes. I set a break-point and it enters it..

Comment: Why is your parameter a string. Change it to `Customer`.

Comment: @venerik It was because I was passing in a Json object?  Was that wrong then. ihave now changed it to Customer though with the FromUri pre-tag

Comment: Although the accepted answer works, normally ASP.Net Web API's model binder binds the json payload to the parameter if it matches.

Comment: @venerik OK, point taken. I will look further. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using **[FromUri]**

To force Web API to read a complex type from the URI, add the `[FromUri]` attribute to the parameter. The following example defines a GeoPoint type, along with a controller method that gets the GeoPoint from the URI.

```
public class GeoPoint
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; } 
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}

public ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromUri] GeoPoint location) { ... }
}
```

The client can put the Latitude and Longitude values in the query string and Web API will use them to construct a GeoPoint. For example:

> http://localhost/api/values/?Latitude=47.678558&Longitude=-122.130989

ASP.NET WebAPI: [Details and examples](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: Fantatsic - that works :) I can accept answer in 4 minutes. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely a mismatch between the client and the server. Your URI specifies a parameter with a name Customer which would match the method's parameter, but you're not supplying any value to that parameter. There is nothing after the `=` sign.

The way you pass the serialized object in your client code, it would actually get to the server as a body of the request. In order to get it as a parameter in your method you should actually use `[FromBody]` attribute and remove the `&Customer=` portion from your URL.

```
[HttpPost]
public Models.CustomerAddress Add([FromBody]string Customer)
{
    //the customer is a json string
}
```

And this would be the client:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Shared.URL);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(Shared.HeaderType));
    string jsonInput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer);
    HttpContent contentPost = new StringContent(jsonInput, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
   var response = client.PostAsync("http://myuri/api/Customer/Add", contentPost).Result;
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    string json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.CustomerAddress>(json);
}
```

This would be a better way to pass data into a `Post` method because you would not need to encode it to satisfy the requirements of the URI format. And sending data in the body of the request can accommodate larger payloads as well.

Comment: @AndrewSimpson - BTW, I've just noticed that you're using `PostAsync().Result`, should change that to `await`, the same as two lines below

Comment: I would like to check out venerik's answer as well.  But, I ahve to leave my PC for a few hours. I will come back to this and adjust accepted answer after I compared all these answers. thanks to everyone!

Comment: Hi, my question has evolved which is not a good thing for people trying to help me. Am i to understand the choice is between using [FromBody] when passing in a string (where the string is a complex object) or no [FromBody] when passing in a complex object?

Comment: Passing data in the body of the request is just another option for POST. GET requests cannot have a body so all the parameters **have** to be passed through the URI. Also, my personal opinion is that classes that derive from **HttpContent** (like the **StringContent** in your code) provide more flexible API than **UriBuilder**.

Comment: hi, I have gone the way that you have recommended.  I have to leave the original accepted answer as it was in relation to passing json via a uri.  I prefer your approach.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change the controller to:

```
[HttpPost]
public Models.CustomerAddress Add(Customer customer)
{
    // customer gets instantiated by the model binder
}
```

The client can now post a request like this:

```
    var jsonCustomer = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer);
    var contentPost = new StringContent(jsonCustomer, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = client.PostAsync("http://myuri/api/Customer/Add", contentPost).Result;
```

Comment: another great example!

Comment: I like the way this is done. A lot cleaner. But would i not also need to include the [FromBody] tag?